# 'Us students' - Does this apposition need a comma?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns, pronouns, noun-phrases

Can a pronoun be used in apposition without comma?

> A few of us students have participated in the match.

This sentence looks quite awkward at first glance.
Is this sentence gramatically correct? I can't find any forbidding rule regarding a relation between pronoun and comma in apposition.

Comment: It's the use of present perfect tense that's awkward. If you're not on the roster, you can't participate. And even if you're a bench warmer, you're still 'participating'. I cannot fathom where the information would be useful to know how many students *have* participated *so far* in *a* match. (is there somewhere in the world where *match* is an acceptable synonym of *tournament*? If you can just walk-on, it's not a match; it's a free-for-all.)

Comment: The meaning is different with and without a comma. "A few of us students have participated…" means" "We are a group of students and a few of us have participated". With a comma (in fact with *two* commas), "A few of us, students, have participated…" means "We are a group of people. A few of us are students, and those students have participated…" With the commas, "A few of us" and "students" *are* in apposition.

Comment: @Mazura "If you can just walk-on, it's not a match; it's a free-for-all" This is "a football match", traditional UK style: https://youtu.be/uYSA4oHrJvs?t=320. The maximum playing time under modern rules has been reduced from the original 48 hours continuously to a mere 8 hours, but "participating *so far*" is still meaningful!

Comment: @alephzero - I knew it must have been *'in British'* but I didn't want to say anything ;)

Comment: I'd have removed the word "have", and written it as "A few of us students participated in the match."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not actually a case of apposition. The phrase *us students* is a single noun phase and  doesn't consist of two adjacent ones.

Basic noun phrases have two main sections, a Determiner and a Head. Typically a Determiner will be a determinative (a word like *the, a, some, any*). The Head of the noun phrase will usually be a smaller phrase built around a noun. In some grammars this type of phrase is called a *nominal* *. In the following example, the Determiner is *these*, and the Head is *slimy dinosaurs*:

- These slimy dinosaurs

Notice that I said that Determiners are *usually* determinatives, and the Heads of noun phrases are *usually* built around a noun. This is because other types of word or phrase can do the job of Determiner in a noun phrase. For example, a Determiner could consist of a genitive noun phrase:

- [That man]'s slimy dinosaurs.

Here we see the noun phrase *that man's* occurring as a Determiner.

Now, normally, when we us a pronoun, it replaces a whole noun phrase:

- **The old bank** is being knocked down.
- **It** is being knocked down.

In the example above the pronoun *it* replaces the whole noun phrase *the old bank*. Because pronouns work like this, we normally consider pronouns themselves to be noun phrases, and usually expect them to replace a whole phrase. However, in the same way that we saw the noun phrase *that man* occuring as a Determiner in *that man's slimy dinosaurs*, we sometimes see pronouns occurring in Determiner function too:

- you bastards
- we band of brothers
- us teachers
- them bastards (non-standard)

Noun phrases like these are quite rare, but they are perfectly grammatical.

**The Original Poster's example**

> A few of **us students** have participated in the match.

In the example above, the object of the preposition *of* is the noun phrase *us students*. This phrase has the pronoun *us* as Determiner and the noun *students* as the Head. This is not a case of apposition. Notice that if we don't use a Determiner here, the sentence will be ungrammatical:

- A few of students have participated in the match.

---

<sup>* For example *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002).</sup>